# How to terminate async function when the Qt dialog is closed

Tags: qt, asynchronous, qwidget, qthread, qtconcurrent

#### Background

I have a dialog which runs a time-consuming operation on its initialization. I wrapped this operation into an asynchronous function in order not to freeze the GUI.

#### Example

Imagine a dialog/widget which shows the current weather fetched asynchronously from a remote server:

```
Dialog::Dialog()
{
    auto label = new QLabel(this);
    QtConcurrent::run([=]() {
        const int temperature = getWeather(); // Time-consuming function
        label->setText(temperature);
    });
    // The rest code, layouts initialization, etc.
}
```

#### Problem

If this dialog/widget is closed before the asynchronous operation is finished, the `label->setText()` part will obviously lead to a crash because the widget object won't exist by that moment.

#### Question

What is the proper way to deal such situations? Probably, I should use something else instead of `QtConcurrent` (`QThread`, for example) in order to properly cancel the asynchronous function when the dialog is closed.

#### Note

Note that the actual code is about reading a bunch of files, **not** about networking, that's why using the async `QNetworkRequest` interface is not a case.

Comment: I think `QtConcurent::run()` doesn't fit to your approach, because, as Qt docs say: "QtConcurrent::run() does not support canceling, pausing, or progress reporting...". You might use `QThread` or just prevent your dialog from closing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// global or class member
QFutureWatcher<int> g_watcher;

Dialog::Dialog()
{
    connect(&g_watcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished, this, &Dialog::handleFinished);

    QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run([]() -> int
    {
        int temperature = getWeather(); // Time-consuming function

        return temperature;
    });

    g_watcher.setFuture(future);
}

void Dialog::handleFinished()
{
    // will never crash because will not be called when Dialog destroyed
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(g_watcher.result()));
}
```

There is also possible to disconnect everything connected to the finished signal:

```
disconnect(&g_watcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished, 0, 0);
```

p.s. As for cancel the async operation, it cannot be cancelled correctly by `QtConcurrent` or `QThread` methods.

There is [QThread::terminate()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) method, but from the doc:

> ...Warning: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The
>   thread can be terminated at any point in its code path...

Therefore you have to implement some "cancel" flag inside your `getWeather()` function, or do as written above.

Answer (score 0):

`QtConcurrent::run()` will return you a `QFuture<T>`. You should be able to call `QFuture::waitForFinished` on it.

The other thing is that you should not be allowed to call `QLabel::setText` from another thread, use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` instead or emit a signal.

Comment: Doesn't the `QFuture::waitForFinished` go against the the initial idea of preventing the GUI freeze described in the **Background** section? Regarding your second remark, I'll check it, thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure but when the application is quitting, the user will not notice the freeze in a hidden window.
I would wait for the future to be finished when the application is quit or when your widgets dtor is called.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a main window, just a dialog. Closing it does not quit the application, so the `QFuture::waitForFinished` will block the GUI.